# Parenting to Meta Rig shrinks my mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

Whenever I parent my mesh with the meta rig, the mesh shrinks down to a microscopic size. Why is this happening?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Any criticisms or tips for better meshes for rigging are welcome! Let me know if there is anything else wrong with how I've set up my mesh.

Here is the project file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KqErHu509sz7ANzQq8fToastt0suVevF/view?usp=sharing

I am looking to model and rig more characters and I want to break any bad habits I may be developing.

Any help is appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: Have you applied scale to both?   if you are using Rigify you want to parent to the generated rig not the meta

Comment: Ah, you're right. I hadn't applied scale to everything. I thought that if I had everything selected and applied scale then it would work on all of them. Lesson learned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your mesh is very dense. It has way too many vertices for animation (almost 300k). Better go low-poly (10k-15k) and bake normal maps for the wrinkles.

Comment: Thanks Blunder! Super helpful. Just decimated a ton of polys off my mesh and it works so much faster now. Really great to keep in mind